# C++ game missile collision detection

Tags: c++, collision, detection

I'm recreating the classic game Asteroids and I'm having some problems with getting the collision detection working correctly. Currently, the below code works well, but for some reason it will only detect collisions on the last missile that has been fired. What I mean is if I fire 3 missiles in a straight line at a stationary asteroid, the first two will pass through the asteroid whilst only the last one will collide with it and act as intended. I'm not quite sure why this is happening but I think it has something to do with iterating through the list of missiles.

Here's the partially working function that is used to detect collisions:

```
void checkMissileAsteroidCollision(struct particle *ast, struct particle *mis)
{
        float missileX = 0;
        float missileY = 0;

        float asteroidX = 0;
        float asteroidY = 0;
        float asteroidSize = 0;

    for( ; mis ; mis = mis->next ) 
    {
            missileX = mis->x;
            missileY = mis->y;

        for( ; ast ; ast = ast->next)
        {
            asteroidX = ast->x;
            asteroidY = ast->y;
            asteroidSize = ast->size;

            if(missileX < asteroidX + asteroidSize &&
                 missileX > asteroidX &&
                 missileY < asteroidY + asteroidSize &&
                 missileY > asteroidY && mis->draw == 1 && ast->draw == 1)
            {
                collisionCounter++;
                ast->draw = 0;
                mis->draw = 0;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The particle struct;

```
typedef struct particle{
    float x;
        float y;
    float vx;
        float vy;
        float heading;
    float dur;
        int size;
        int draw;
    struct particle *next;
} node_t;
```

I've included two links below that link to the whole source file and its header where this code comes from, in case any other information is needed to figure out why this is happening.

gamestate.cpp: https://gist.github.com/Jakemangan/d286ef1f9159e6682778ec2e0daf516c

gamestate.h: https://gist.github.com/Jakemangan/6c3788a46825a86cd0e2642864fcad68

Comment: Such list handling is an extremely bad practice in C++. You should use standard containers instead, such as `std::vector`. The variables you introduce as helpers should also be const and declared when they are first assigned, not at the top of the function. As for your actual problem, there's not enough information here to reproduce it. Try writing a unit test that passes some example data and checks the result.

Comment: Care to elaborate more on why a custom linked list is "extremely bad practice"? Also I don't think he asked for code styling help...

Comment: [Here's a draft of such a unit test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5292512c0e622896). Your routine is almost ready for testing (the global collision counter is the only problem).

Comment: @RonE That would take more than a comment can fit, but, in random order - it's error prone, hard to read (as you've just demonstrated), hard to maintain, hard to use (write), and it's not styling - it's essential functionality and correctness of the produced solutions. You also can't benefit from any existing algorithms.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz You are literally the first person I've seen complain about a custom linked list in 20 years. Also it's pretty easy to read (I misread a for loop, a STL linked list would not help there), write (Compsci 101 doesn't cover advanced topics and covers linked lists) and maintenance is no more than using an STL container. Also using algorithms relies on an interface, not a specify parent class so that's not a problem either.

Comment: @RonE I complain about it all the time. Aside from obvious homework or other learning exercise questions, the answer is almost always "stop doing what you're doing and use `std::list` if you really need a linked list, otherwise use `std::vector`." The standard library containers are much better optimized and almost certain to have fewer bugs than the implementations you will find on SO.

Comment: @RonE in order - then you mustn't have been very active here, no (and that's why you failed at reading it, it would help - see my answer), no (containers aren't "advanced"), no. And the interface for structs mixing concerns of storage and data model is universally horrendous.

Comment: And to make it clear - were we talking C, my answers and reaction would be entirely different. But given the modern C++ toolset and goals, forcing such primitive approaches on beginners is actively harmful.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz No I'm not very active here, and you've misread my comment. Also structs and classes in c++ are the same, so any complaints about interfaces on structs also apply to classes.

Comment: @RonE I can complain as well! I am currently maintaining a legacy system where the custom lists aren't generic and only link via pointers - this means that the debugging tools are much harder to use to inspect the data and also there are multiple different versions of the different custom lists - I would _*MUCH*_ (I can't seem to emphasize that word enough) rather have standard containers for those data structures!

Comment: I'd just like to gently point out that the question is about collision detection, not about what coding style is best.

Answer (score 5):

```
for( ; ast ; ast = ast->next)
```

This line is the problem.  After this loop terminates, `ast` is null but it is not reset for the next iteration of the outer `mis` loop.  This means that only the first iteration of the `mis` loop actually sees any asteroids.

To correct this, declare a new variable for this loop:

```
for(struct particle *ast2 = ast ; ast2 ; ast2 = ast2->next)
```

(Or choose a better name than `ast2`.) Then, obviously, replace `ast` with `ast2` in the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

This is how a more modern C++ version could look like:

```
// drop the pointer from the struct

void checkMissileAsteroidCollision(std::vector<particle>& asteroids, std::vector<particle>& missiles)
{
    for(auto & mis : missiles) 
    {
        for(auto & ast : asteroids)
        {
            const auto missileX = mis.x;
            const auto missileY = mis.y;
            const auto asteroidX = ast.x;
            const auto asteroidY = ast.y;
            const auto asteroidSize = ast.size;

            if(missileX < asteroidX + asteroidSize &&
                 missileX > asteroidX &&
                 missileY < asteroidY + asteroidSize &&
                 missileY > asteroidY && mis.draw == 1 && ast.draw == 1)
            {
                collisionCounter++;
                ast.draw = false;
                mis.draw = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then example creation and use:

```
std::vector<particle> asteroids { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, true } };
std::vector<particle> missiles { { 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, true } };

checkMissileAsteroidCollision(asteroids, missiles);

std::cout << std::boolalpha << asteroids[0].draw;
```

There are more improvements to be made here (encapsulation in a class, not taking parameters to mutate, not using `draw` as collision flag), but I believe those belong to Code Review and I encourage you to post your solution there once you get it to work.

Comment: All of these auto's increase compile time, and increase misdirection. This is actually harder for me to read than the original. I can also create a custom linked list that uses an iterator and take advantage of a foreach loop so nothing special there. Otherwise this is the same.

Comment: @RonE It's harder for you to read because you're stuck doing C++ from 20 years ago. I suggest you try out writing in (and reading) the modern code for more than 15 minutes and then reevaluate your opinion. At this point, you're not arguing with me - you're arguing with the community consensus, pretty much. And nothing's preventing you from writing a "custom linked list that uses an iterator" and posting your own answer - let the votes decide, then. I'd rather not argue this and drag the comment thread anymore.

Comment: oh I've definitely written modern C++ for more than 15 mins, and you've addressed none of my issues. It may be easier to read for you, but what type are those autos? what methods can I call on them? how do I know what docs to look up? what about compile time?

Comment: @RonE No data to back this up, but I'd be very surprised if the use of `auto` here increases compile times in any way. The compiler needs to check the assignments anyway, so it needs to know the type of the RHS as it is.

Comment: If _the type of the autos_ is important, you also need to know the type on the right-hand-side of the assignment (in case you're invoking a custom conversion operator). So without `auto`, you still have the same effective level of indirection, the same requirement to check docs or code to find that type, but an additional coupling if you change that type.

Comment: @Useless not true at all, with the left hand side declared you have the type in front of you. Without it declared (or declared as auto) you have to guess. Here's when Bjourne Stroustrup says to use it (and it's not on every variable like this developer suggests) http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#auto

Comment: @TristanBrindle in this small of a code sample no it won't. in a much larger codebase it most definitely will. type inference is not free, the compiler has to walk the tree.

Comment: No, with the LHS type declared, you know what type the local variable is. To know what the assignment does, you _also_ need to know the RHS type, which _still_ means looking it up. I'm saying that if the type of the local variable is critically important, it's very likely that the type of the RHS is also critically important, and you didn't get any benefit from the extra typing.

Comment: Equivalently, even when you declare the LHS type, the compiler needs to know the RHS type before _it_ can figure out what the assignment does. So, no saving there either. The only thing you've added is an assumption about what type the RHS is, which may be (or become) mistaken - and it can be a silent mistake if there's an implicit conversion.